# How to tune performance of below python code

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a code in python which will take 3 numbers a, n and m as input. Suppose a=120, n =3 and m=5, the program should output 120120120%5 as output. That is, the first number will be repeated n times to get new number and that number modulo m should be the output. The below program takes the value of these 3 numbers with number of test values given by 'T'. However the testing program says that it exceeds execution time limit of 4 seconds. How can I improve the python code

```
#Define function
def appmod(a,n,m):
       fn=str(a)*n
       return int(fn)%m





b=[]    
T=int(input ('Enter the number of test cases: '))


for i in range(T):
  A,N,M=input("Enter the values for A,N and M: ").split()
  c=appmod(int(A),int(N),int(M))
  b.append(c)
for s in b:
  print (s)
```

Comment: Why do you convert `a` to an int, only to convert it back to a string in `appmod`? When you say this takes 4 seconds, how many test cases are you dealing with?

Comment: This is a problem in codechef website. Not sure what input file they are using to run the program

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer? So from what I understand you have to upload/paste the code to an online interpreter, which tests it. This test fails because the execution time limit is exceeded. Can you make clear what exactly you provide to `codechef`? How does this online supply the inputs for the function. If you ask the online interpreter to ask for input, where would it get this?